# Выпадающий NumberPicker при клике на виджет

Tags: java, android

Каким образом можно сделать такое "выпадающее" меню:
по нажатию на эту кнопку:

[image: start]

появляется вот такое меню:
[image: onClick]

где при нажатии на стрелочку вверх цифра увеличивается,а при нажатии на стрелочку
 вниз - наоборот

Comment: Картинки перезалейте, ничего не понятно

Comment: я хотел узнать не существует ли каких-либо виджетов ,которые позволят упростить сей процесс , на основе которых можно это реализовать.

Comment: Премного благодарен!

Comment: @pavlofff Пожалуйста, опубликуйте предлагаемое решение ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таких виджетов нет в стандартном SDK, но и в его реализации тоже ничего сложного нет.

Делаете `View` в "полный" размер, разместив две части в отдельных контейнерах (напр. `LinearLayout`).

Части, что снизу присваиваете атрибут `android:visibility="gone"`. Затем программно управляете видимостью этой нижней части - при клике по верхней части устанавливаете для нижней видимость - `bottomView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` ну и тд.
Для нижней можете использовать стандартный `NumberPicker` или сделать свой.

Примерная реализация может выглядеть так.

`enterNumber` - текущее введенное значение для использования в программе.

Первое нажатие на верхнюю часть раскрывает пикер для ввода значения, повторное нажатие на верхнюю часть скрывает пикер и отображает выбранное в пикере значение в верхней части.

**Код**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    TextView topText;
    TextView topNumber;
    NumberPicker numberPicker;
    View topView;
    View bottomView;
    int enterNumber = 1;
    boolean isFullView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        topText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topText);
        topNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.topNumber);
        numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
        topView =  findViewById(R.id.topView);
        bottomView =  findViewById(R.id.bottomView);

        topText.setText("Some Text");
        topNumber.setText(String.valueOf(enterNumber));

        numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(9);
        numberPicker.setValue(enterNumber);

        topView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bottomView.setVisibility(isFullView ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                isFullView = !isFullView;
                topNumber.setText(String.valueOf(enterNumber));

            }
        });

        numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

                enterNumber = newVal;

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">


     <LinearLayout
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/topView">

         <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/topText"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:padding="6dp" />

         <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/topNumber"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:padding="6dp" />
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/bottomView"
         android:visibility="gone">

         <NumberPicker
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
     </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Вы можете добавить анимацию, кастомизировать `NumberPicker` или еще что то , это только минимальная заготовка.