# Как в андроид сделать кнопку-список (без ActionBar)?

Tags: java, android, list, button

Коротко о проблеме:
Есть кнопка

[image: Вот она]

Если на нее нажать то должен выплыть под ней список с другими кнопками. Вот так

[image: Так должно быть].

И по нажатию снова на "OPT" тот список должен уйти под эту же кнопку. Вопрос - как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: это довольно просто: под кнопкой делаете скрытый вью с остальными кнопками (видимость gone), при нажатии на первую -ставите ему видимость, повторное нажатие - убираете ее. все это анимируете для красоты.

Comment: Благодарю, это мне отлично подходит) останется только разобраться с анимацией)

Comment: вот [похожий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/638698/177345) я делал, там и про анимацию/ еще [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/437822/177345)

Comment: если нужно чтобы кнопки не раздвигали экран при раскрытии, а были поверх него, то используйте FrameLayout

Comment: Прекрасно! Это то что нужно! Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Вот [эта](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout) либа может помочь, она умеет красиво скрывать/открывать элементы, нужно только немного подразобраться с ней, но это не сложно.

Comment: если уж говорить про библиотеки, то есть и [более подходящие](https://github.com/Karumi/ExpandableSelector) к вопросу

Comment: несомненно, но данная тоже вполне может помочь решить проблему